# CardView Background Color Change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, background-color, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` that changes function once clicked. To confirm this change, I have a `TextView` within the `CardView` that changes from Start to Stop. I thought I could change the BG color from green to red by the same way I change the text, but it is not working.

Does anybody know how I could change the background color from GREEN to RED once clicked? It is currently green. I have tried using the `onPressed` attribute in XML however the color does not remain RED once the `CardView` is clicked.

I will post the code below. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To change cardView background color programatically use

```
 your_card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Primary));
```

Comment: I know tat is how you change it programatically, however what I am asking is how do you change color once CLICKED

Comment: just write it inside `onClick(..)` method !! @androidmac

Comment: Unfortunately still will not work. If you can see above, I can get the status of the text to change onClick, but not the bg color.

Comment: you must be having other problems then.. @androidmac

Answer (score 1):

> values-Color

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#009688</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#d7d6d4</color>
```